# How to calculate work when a block is moving with constant velocity?

Tags: acceleration, work

How to calculate work when a block is moving with constant velocity?
As we know $f=ma$, and for constant velocity $a=0$, so $f=0$ and $w=fs=0$? Can anybody make it clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your argument were fine, no energy would have been required for anything in this universe and there wouldn't have been an energy crisis !!! Your intuition is fine when there is no resisting force acting on your body. Say, you want to move a block of mass $m$ applying a horizontal force with constant velocity $v$ on a floor with friction coefficient $\mu$. Then we know that frictional force $f = \mu mg$. Hence you need to keep applying a force $F$ equal in magnitude but opposite in direction to the frictional force to keep the body moving at $v$. And hence the work = $F.v$ which is definitely non zero.

Comment: Thanks Sandeep. May be I got the point. You meant that, net force may be zero as Force(imposed)=-Force(friction) in this particular case where velocity remains constant. But imposed force should be counted that i missed out. Am I right?

Comment: Exactly. You got the point.

Answer (score -1):

Work done is the scalar product of Force and displacement along the direction of the force, so work done should be zero since net force on the object is zero, hence the constant velocity. That means W = 0.

Answer (score -1):

Explaining it in a different way;  F=Ma, so for constant velocity there is no apparent acceleration or a = 0 apparently,  so Work = F *D or =F*s = 0 apparently,  but  intuitively we know there is work being done, for example a train is moving 100,000 tons of weight at constant "v" along the track,  the answer is that the apparently missing "a" is really exactly = to all opposing forces including frictional resistance "u" (the track has a resistance to the train wheels).  So when the accel is = to the friction resistance on flat surface, there is still accel needed to overcome the resistance;  Other times "a" is more or less, and there is an "apparent" "a" (speeds up or slows down): So the real work calculation must factor in the friction resistance "u" to be accurate & all other resistances such as gravity vector when going up or down a hill.  In space there is virtually 0 resistive forces, thus even a slight F on a space vehicle (ie solar sail) will result in steady "a" and the corresponding steady increase in speed "v". Imho.   Www.Inventpeace@aol.com 2 see insanely unbelievable very simple (elegant*) patented electric/electronic circuit that gets massively more energy out of alkaline batteries; Key is factories have 2 force in much more energy than they ever expect you to get out: also this circuit by using a specific technique to "up" the voltage gets "auto-regeneration" to be a major instead of minor factor.  Check it out  at the link for battery circuit on the webpage www.inventpeace.com or email to inventpeace@aol.com  Would partner with backer to get it into world.

*Elegant via its super simple and super low parts count of only one 10 c2nt part for small motorized versions & only 3 small 10 cent parts for other devices such as flashlights, while even camera's (with miniaturization) only need 2 more low cost parts!  Its win-win-win ! Problem is its so good, people refuse to believe it until they see it in operation.